# Mysql select all records that are greater than some date time

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select all records from table where `date1` is greater than other `date2`. `Date1` is a `datetime` field in MySQL. `Date2` is a `datetime` object in PHP. I want to compare not only the date but and the time. This is my not working query.

```
$sql = 'SELECT t.* 
        from transire t 
        where t.returning > '.$transire->returning.';';
```

Error:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error
in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Ok I understand, I cant compare php datetime object like that but what is the correct way to do this ? Sure I can use Date(t.returning) but I also need the time in that day. All events after current datetime. I searched and found a few answers but none of them helped me. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT t.* from transire t where t.returning > "'.$transire->returning.'";';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double quote for your variable in php, and add a single quote around your date:

```
$sql = "SELECT t.* from transire t where t.returning > '".$transire->returning."'";
```

And avoid sql injection by escaping your variable.

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\rma\application\modules\rma\controllers\TransireController.php on line 1107

So it must be a string ? And compare strings ?